# Use function as a parameter to traverse binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given `typedef struct covid *covidDB;`

I have two functions here:

```
unsigned long countResult(covidDB cur) {
    unsigned long tmp = 0;
    if (isEmpty(cur)) return 0;
    tmp += countResult(cur->left);
    for (int day = 1; day <= 70; day++) {
        if (cur->patients[day] > 0) {
            tmp += cur->patients[day];
        }
    }
    return tmp + countResult(cur->right);
}
```

and

```
void printDB(covidDB cur) {
    if (isEmpty(cur)) return;
    printDB(cur->left);
    for (int day = 1; day <= 70; day++) {
        if (cur->patients[day] > 0)
            show
    }
    printDB(cur->right);
}
```

Apperently both two functions do inorder traversal through the binary tree.
Is it possible to write something like:

```
void inorder(covidDB cur, /*function*/) {
    //do something
}
```

and in the main function I call

```
inorder(root, printList);
inorder(root, countList);
```

Comment: You can use function pointers

Comment: You can define the second argument of your function `inorder` as a function pointer to pass function `printList` or `countList`. Both functions and the function pointer must have the same signature. If e.g. `countList` does some calculation and returns the (preliminary) result, then `printList` must nevertheless accept the same parameters and return something. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/840669/10622916

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that, just you should set the return value types of your passing functions the same as `unsigned long`:

```
unsigned long (*func)(covidDB cur);

 void inorder(covidDB cur, unsigned long (*func)(covidD cur)) {
    func(cur);
}
```